# How to save ImageCache to the disk in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, image-caching

I load lots of image from the internet with Image.network statement and I know the ImageCache only save them until then the app is running. But I want save cache, because I don't want always downloading images, when app starting.
So: save cache to the disk is possible in flutter?

Answer (score 1):

Flutter's [image cache](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/ImageCache-class.html) is for decoded images. It sounds like what you want is a cache of encoded image files.

You could build this yourself by downloading to files to device storage and using `Image.file`, but you'd probably want to implement some kind of eviction logic to make sure you don't consume too much space on the device.

You could use `Image.asset` for static images that you want to bundle with your app.

Consider preloading your images before the user gets to the point where they are displayed. This will create the illusion that they load instantly.

Comment: "eviction" logic?

Comment: @ThinkDigital "Eviction" means deleting from the cache.